# How to tie up Spring integration error handling and RabbitMQ error handling to requeue message failed with some skipped exception?

Tags: java, spring, groovy, rabbitmq, spring-integration

How to tie up Spring integration errorChannel (error handling) and RabbitMQ error handling (listenerContainer's errorChannel) to requeue message failed with some skipped exception??

I have a `Spring`-based project written on `Groovy` with usage of `RabbitMQ`.
The configuration is:

```
    <int:service-activator id="GlobalErrorHandler" input-channel="errorChannel" 
ref="globalErrorHandler"/>

    <int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter id="event-processing-inbound-rabbit-adapter"
                                          channel="mli-forever-event-processing-channel"
                                          error-channel="errorChannel"
                                          mapped-request-headers="*"
                                          listener-container="listenerContainer"/>
```

and

```
@Bean
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer( final CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory, 
       final ApplicationProperties configuration ) {

        new SimpleMessageListenerContainer( connectionFactory ).with {
            concurrentConsumers = configuration.concurrentConsumers
            queueNames = configuration.rabbitQueueName
            autoDeclare = true
            it
        }
    }
```

The error-handler to just a logging:

```
class GlobalErrorHandler extends AbstractFeedbackAware {
    @ServiceActivator
    void handleMessagingException( final MessagingException exception ) {
        feedbackProvider.sendFeedback( CoreFeedbackContext.CONSUMING_EVENT_ERROR, exception.message )
    }
}
```

If I get the exception `PersistenceException` the message don't requeue, but it should.
I do googling and reading the documentation, and I don't understand the error way if the exception occurs. What if add the `errorHandler` to the `containerListener` what of the handlers will be called?? Both?? What the order??
I was thinking about some that stuff:

```
new SimpleMessageListenerContainer( null ).with {
    errorHandler = { it instanceof PersistenceException } as ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler
    it
}
class ExceptionStrategyToAvoidPersistenceException extends ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler.DefaultExceptionStrategy {

    @Override
    boolean isFatal( final Throwable t ) {
        super.isFatal( t ) && !( t instanceof PersistenceException )
    }
}
```

but I don't understand why the the `PersistenceException` don't requeue, since it's not in the list of the fatals error of the default exception strategy.
Could some body help me with the solution?? Or give some explanation?? Or how to reproduce the error in the integration test, since I can't limit the DB's (`PostgreSQL`) space in the `Docker`-container??

Will be very grateful!!

Answer (score 0):

The `error-channel` flow is called first; it must re-throw the exception to cause the message to be requeued.